# What Can I Do To Optimise This Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query that does an inner join across three tables. Here are the definitions for each of these three tables.

`stitching_output_oc`

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table stitching_output_oc
(
    output_oc_unique_id  int auto_increment
        primary key,
    batches_unique_id_fk int                                not null,
    oc_number            char(22)                           not null,
    product_code         char(10)                           null,
    product_description  char(90)                           null,
    colour_code          char(10)                           not null,
    colour_description   char(60)                           null,
    creation_stamp       datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    update_stamp         datetime                           null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint batch_output_unique
        unique (batches_unique_id_fk, oc_number, product_code, colour_code),
    constraint stitching_dispatch_OC_fk
        foreign key (batches_unique_id_fk) references stitching_batches (stitching_batches_unique_id)
            on delete cascade
);
```

`stitching_output_size`

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table stitching_output_size
(
    output_size_unique_id  int auto_increment
        primary key,
    output_oc_unique_id_fk int                                not null,
    size                   char(10)                           not null,
    output_quantity        decimal  default 0                 null,
    fit_type               char(50)                           null,
    creation_stamp         datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    update_stamp           datetime                           null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint stitching_output_size_fk
        foreign key (output_oc_unique_id_fk) references stitching_output_oc (output_oc_unique_id)
            on delete cascade
);
```

`stitching_batches`

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table stitching_batches
(
    stitching_batches_unique_id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    batch_number                char(10)                                              not null,
    location                    char(10)                                              not null,
    status                      enum ('active', 'inactive') default 'active'          not null,
    work_start_time             time                        default '00:00:00'        not null,
    work_end_time               time                        default '00:00:00'        not null,
    break_start_time            time                        default '00:00:00'        not null,
    break_end_time              time                        default '00:00:00'        not null,
    creation_stamp              datetime                    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null,
    update_stamp                datetime                                              null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint batch_number
        unique (batch_number, location)
);
```

The query is given below

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
Select stitchingOC.oc_number as ocNumber, stitchingOC.product_code as productCode,
 DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
 DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, "%H:%i") as hourMinutes,
 stitchingBatch.batch_number as batchNumber,
 sum(stitchingSize.output_quantity)as outputQuantity
 from stitching_output_size stitchingSize
 inner join stitching_output_oc stitchingOC on stitchingOC.output_oc_unique_id = stitchingSize.output_oc_unique_id_fk
 inner join stitching_batches stitchingBatch on stitchingBatch.stitching_batches_unique_id = stitchingOC.batches_unique_id_fk
 where IF('' IS NULL || '' = 'null' || TRIM('')  = '', stitchingBatch.batch_number like ('%'), stitchingBatch.batch_number like('')) and
 DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y%m%d') >= '20220420'  and
 DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y%m%d') <= IF('20220420' IS NULL || '20220420' = 'null' || TRIM('20220420')  = '', '20220420', '20220420')
 and stitchingBatch.location = 'IDU1'
 group by stitchingBatch.batch_number, DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, "%H:%i"), stitchingOC.oc_number, stitchingOC.product_code
 order by stitchingBatch.batch_number, DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, "%H:%i"), stitchingOC.oc_number, stitchingOC.product_code desc;
```

Here's the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
"-> Sort: stitchingBatch.batch_number, `date`, hourMinutes, stitchingOC.oc_number, stitchingOC.product_code DESC  (actual time=172.412..172.429 rows=21 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.003..0.023 rows=21 loops=1)
        -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=172.296..172.343 rows=21 loops=1)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=2730.96 rows=7601) (actual time=26.777..171.803 rows=122 loops=1)
                -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=70.50 rows=16) (actual time=0.067..1.909 rows=153 loops=1)
                    -> Index scan on stitchingOC using batch_output_unique  (cost=16.25 rows=155) (actual time=0.042..0.213 rows=155 loops=1)
                    -> Filter: ((stitchingBatch.location = 'IDU1') and (0 <> if(<cache>((true)),(stitchingBatch.batch_number like '%'),(stitchingBatch.batch_number like ''))))  (cost=0.25 rows=0) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=1 loops=155)
                        -> Single-row index lookup on stitchingBatch using PRIMARY (stitching_batches_unique_id=stitchingOC.batches_unique_id_fk)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=155)
                -> Filter: ((date_format(stitchingSize.creation_stamp,'%Y%m%d') >= '20220420') and (date_format(stitchingSize.creation_stamp,'%Y%m%d') <= <cache>(if((false),'20220420','20220420'))))  (cost=125.77 rows=490) (actual time=1.105..1.107 rows=1 loops=153)
                    -> Index lookup on stitchingSize using stitching_output_size_fk (output_oc_unique_id_fk=stitchingOC.output_oc_unique_id)  (cost=125.77 rows=490) (actual time=0.074..0.704 rows=395 loops=153)
"
```

Things I've tried so far:

1. Removing the `IF` conditions from the SQL query. I can handle that kind of processing in the code because I have processing power to spare but the SQL query is the bottleneck right now.
   However, removing that didn't make much of a difference to the execution
2. Removing the order by clause so I can handle it in code. This reduces the execution time a little bit because the sort from the query plan gets removed which is a big chunk of it.

However, I'm trying to understand if there is something more obvious I'm missing here - maybe like defining a covering index on one of the tables perhaps?
I'm at a loss though because the bottle necks don't seem to be the inner joins, it seems to be the temp table creation which I'm not sure how to avoid.

**NOTE**

I know the time is stored in a poor format in the `stitching_batches` table but that's just something we have to live with right now.

Comment: Are there no other indexes than what we see in the table definitions? How many rows are in each table?

Comment: @AndyLester Nope, all indexes are as defined in DDL provided.
The largest table is `stitching_output_size` which contains around 60k rows. The other two contain less than 200 each.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Read about [sargability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean).

Answer (score 4):

The quickest thing to do is to look at how you can use indexes to improve the speed of the condition checks in your WHERE clause.

For example, you have `stitchingBatch.location = 'IDU1'` as a condition in the WHERE clause, so add an index on `stitchingBatch.location`.

Unfortunately the bulk of your WHERE is conditional stuff that will not be able to use the indexes.

This condition here:

```
IF('' IS NULL || '' = 'null' || TRIM('')  = '',
 stitchingBatch.batch_number like ('%'), stitchingBatch.batch_number like(''))
```

isn't going to be able to use any indexes.

What's the purpose of checks like `'' IS NULL` and `'' = 'null'` which are always going to false, and `TRIM('')  = ''` which will always be true?  Get rid of it all.

The date filtering could use an index on `stitchingSize.creation_stamp`, but only if you change your WHERE clause.  Instead of converting the date type to a string, use dates directly.  So instead of

```
DATE_FORMAT(stitchingSize.creation_stamp, '%Y%m%d') >= '20220420'
```

you use

```
stitchingSize.creation_stamp >= STR_TO_DATE('20220420, '%Y%m%d')
```

Your original version converts the stamp in every row to a string, and then compares it to another string. It has to do this once for every row in the table. My version converts a string to a date only once, and then compares the dates natively.  If you had an index on creation_stamp, then MySQL could just look in the index to see which rows it should check.

https://use-the-index-luke.com is a good introduction to how to use indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your optimisations are good ideas but from the query plan, it doesn't look like that's going to save me much time, is it? Or am I misunderstanding the query plan?
It looks like the bulk of time is spent aggregating the temp table and sorting it. Is there any way to optimise that portion? 

Also, the if conditions are in place because they are handling something that should be handled by a controller. I plan to remove those entirely from the query.

Comment: I believe that it's aggregating a temp table because it can't do things in memory because it can't limit the number of rows it wants to work on. Also, I just realized in your GROUP BY and ORDER BY, you're converting the datetimes to strings so that it drops the hours/minutes/seconds part. Don't do it that way. Just use `DATE(stitchingSize.creation_stamp)`.  Pretty much everything you are doing that is doing conversions to strings, or manipulations of strings, is bad in terms of optimization,.